# C# sending a command over TCP and getting a json back

Tags: c#, .net, windows, http, rest

Basically I am writing a small windows application to send and I am not sure how to send a command over a TCP socket to a local network machine. All the examples I looked up in google look way to complicated for what I am looking to do. so far I have this in my c# program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace MiningMonitorClientW
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new form1());
        string userworker = Textbox1 + TextBox2;
    }


    public static string Textbox1 { get; set; }

    public static string TextBox2 { get; set; }
 }
}
```

basically I'm trying to emulate this code I have in ruby below in C#

sends a command over TCPsocket to the given IP then saves the response which is json.

```
s = TCPSocket.new '192.xxx.x.x', xxxx
s.puts '{"command": "devs"}'
dev_query = s.gets
```

then sends up to a website using http put request

```
path = "/workers/update"
host = "https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com"
puts RestClient.put "#{host}#{path}", updateinfo, {:content_type => :json}
```

I would love to this in c# someone help me!!!1 :D
Thanks!

Well I ended up solving my problem and the code below sends a string over TCP and then receives a json back in a string.

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.x.xxx");
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 4028);

            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            string SummaryMessage = "string to send";
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SummaryMessage);

            sender.Send(msg);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int lengthOfReturnedBuffer = sender.Receive(buffer);
            char[] chars = new char[lengthOfReturnedBuffer];

            Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(buffer, 0, lengthOfReturnedBuffer, chars, 0);
            String returnedJson = new String(chars);
            Console.WriteLine("The Json:{0}", returnedJson);
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: You mean convert ruby to C# ?

Comment: I just want my c# code to do what my ruby code does!

Comment: "translating" programming language is not in SO's scope. Try it yourself

Comment: Ok... can you explain how to setup a TCP socket for in c#? that's specifically what I'm looking for. I can figure the exact stuff out. I just gave my ruby code has reference as what I am trying to accomplish. As per the title says Trying to send string over TCP in c#.

Comment: Please take off hold thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you simply want to make web requests, not to learn TCP communications. Here is partial list of classes you can use for that:

- [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)
- [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)
- [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx)

There are also classes to deal with JSON in [Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) and [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as well outside with [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) is one of most known.

Obviously you can co deeper and use TCP methods of System.Net namespace directly, but it is probably overkill for such scenario.

Comment: Thank you Alexei this is what I was looking for! I did some more digging and got my code working for a TCP request. I am going to update the question with the code I am using.I was wondering if you could explain to me why I send a string encoded in ascii and get returned a string encoded in UTF8 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would setup a TCP/IP WCF service hosted in IIS. It would also work to self host it in a Windows Service/Console App/WinForm app if you don't want to use IIS.

You can then return arbitrary formats from your service - including JSON

Comment: Sounds great but how do I do that in c#?

Comment: Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx